# How to switch free proxies in python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python code to find/check free & working proxies and it was working a year back but now its not working and also not giving any error.

Its just showing
Skipping. Connnection error

Unable to understand what i need to change or modify in the code

````
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
import time
from lxml.html import fromstring
import requests
from itertools import cycle
import traceback
def get_proxies():
   url = 'https://www.sslproxies.org/'
   response = requests.get(url)
   parser = fromstring(response.text)
   proxies = set()
   for i in parser.xpath('//tbody/tr')[:10]:
       if i.xpath('.//td[7][contains(text(),"yes")]'):
          proxy = ":".join([i.xpath('.//td[1]/text()')[0], 
          i.xpath('.//td[2]/text()')[0]])
          proxies.add(proxy)
   return proxies

proxies = get_proxies()
proxy_pool = cycle(proxies)
url = 'https://httpbin.org/ip'
for i in range(1,1111):
#Get a proxy from the pool
    proxy = next(proxy_pool)  
    print("Request #%d"%i)
    try:
            response = requests.get(url,proxies={"http": proxy, "https": proxy},timeout=15)
            print(response.json())
    except:
            print("Skipping. Connnection error")
            
    else:
            print('Success proxy :', proxy)
            
            proxy_ip_port = proxy

            proxy1 = Proxy()
            proxy1.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
            proxy1.http_proxy = proxy_ip_port
            proxy1.ssl_proxy = proxy_ip_port

            capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
            proxy1.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)


            driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/samswaryan/Documents/chromedriver', desired_capabilities=capabilities)

            try:
               driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
              
            except:
                  print('failed')
            else:
                  print('success')


            time.sleep(10)

            driver.quit()```
````

Comment: Are you sure the URL is correct ? `url = 'https://www.sslproxies.org/'`  Maybe navigate to that site and inspect to see if anything has changed.

Comment: https://www.sslproxies.org/
the website is still working